# how to update user database for current user login in php?

Tags: php

i try find answer through this website but every try i do, i got error.. why?
i want the user that login, enable to update their own information. but everytime i click update, nothing is update and keep show "error" here my update.php page script

```
 <?php
 include '../config/config.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$blood_presure = $_POST['blood_presure'];
$heart_rate = $_POST['heart_rate'];


$query = "UPDATE user_info SET name = '$name', hobbies =' $hobbies', height = '$height', weight = '$weight', blood_presure = '$blood_presure' heart_rate = $heart_rate' WHERE   $sessions = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
 header("location:../dashboard.php");
 }

else {
echo "ERROR";
} 



mysql_close();
?>
```

what my mistake, is it correct on how i set WHERE for the user that currently login to update their own data?

Comment: Why are you using the old mysql api?

Comment: owh what you mean?.. i follow from internet that i can get.. i use appserve for database.. previously i already use this code.. and it work find for update other database that not depend on session.. but when i try to update current user data that depend on sesion, i cant.. i dont know how to make it work

Comment: What is the error? You missed single quotes in here. `heart_rate = $heart_rate'`

Comment: it just show "error" that i echo... that mean it wont update my database... i dont know what my mistake... ouch.. hmm still error

Comment: Add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in else part.

Comment: @Ranjith it show 6135? what that?

Comment: mysql_* was deprecated in php 5.5 use **[mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[pdo_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

Comment: owh... i dont know mysqli or pdo? any idea i can follow?

Comment: Is any column has `integer` data type?

Comment: just a user_id is int

Comment: I don't see any `user_id` column in here. Can show of you table structure with your question?

Comment: should i put this $sessions = $_SESSION['user'] under include?

Comment: here my database http://imgur.com/yZr3VRH

Comment: @Ranjith user_id currently just use for login..

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE user_info SET name = '$name', hobbies =' $hobbies', height = '$height where user_name='';

try this add where clause and add any condition according to your requirement?

Comment: i try make it like this
$query = "UPDATE user_info SET name = '$name', hobbies =' $hobbies', height = '$height', weight = '$weight', blood_presure = '$blood_presure', heart_rate = '$heart_rate' WHERE username = '$session'";

and i put this along my other post variable
$sessions = $_SESSION['user'];

still data not change but no error

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i just manage to solve this.. this is my solution

```
    <?php 
   session_start();
    if (!session_is_registered(user))
  {
   header("location:login.php");
}
?>
<?php
include '../config/config.php';


 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
 $height = $_POST['height'];
 $weight = $_POST['weight'];
 $blood_presure = $_POST['blood_presure'];
 $heart_rate = $_POST['heart_rate'];
 $sessions = $_SESSION['user'];

  $sql = "UPDATE user_info SET name = '$name', hobbies = '$hobbies', height = '$height', weight = '$weight', blood_presure = '$blood_presure', heart_rate = '$heart_rate' WHERE username = '$sessions'";
  $result= mysql_query($sql);

  if($result){
  header("location:../dashboard.php");
  }

  else {
  echo error_reporting(E_ALL);
  } 



  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

i need to put start session and variable for session

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/tr/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_ functions.